# C# работа с диском

Tags: c#

Как получить адрес первого сектора, в котором хранится файл?
Цепочку секторов файла?

Comment: P/Invoke is your friend.

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать SetFilePointerEx , не путать с SetFilePointer

```
LARGE_INTEGER diskOffset;
diskOffset.QuadPart = _nSect * 512LL;
SetFilePointerEx(hDisk, diskOffset, nullptr, FILE_BEGIN);
```

Это работает с SetFilePointer тоже, но все-равно нужен LARGE_INTEGER :

```
SetFilePointer(hFile, diskOffset.LowPart, &diskOffset.HighPart, FILE_BEGIN);
```

Вы можете использовать тип long вместо LARGE_INTEGER для SetFilePointerEx

Comment: Эээ... А каким образом file pointer отмапить на адрес сектора?